# Make web-mode always indent with spaces

Tags: indentation, web-mode

I am using emacs [web-mode](http://web-mode.org/), and the tabbing in JS files seems to be acting strangely.

I have tab set to indent 2 spaces, but when the indent reaches 8 spaces, web-mode turns them into a tab, and then continues to tab 2 spaces until in reaches another 8, and converts that into another tab, etc.

Can I stop this from happening and tell emacs/web-mode to only ever indent spaces?

**EDIT:**

Here is a short nested function example:

```
(function() {
  function() {
    function() {
      function() {
    function() {
      // Indenting problem.
    }
      }
    }
  }
})()
```

It's obviously showing up fine in Emacs, but you can see the indentation problem here.

I will note here that this also occurs in javascript-mode.

Comment: Is this specific to web mode? Or does it happen anywhere?

Comment: This is only happening on web-mode, everything else tabs fine with spaces indefinitely.

Comment: Sorry, javascript mode does the same thing as well. But it's just those two.

Comment: Which `javascript-mode` are you using, the builtin one? Also, does this happen when indenting html in `web-mode`?

Comment: Please post the content of your init file. Emacs uses a tab for 8 spaces by default, so there must be something in your init file to turn it off for most modes.

Comment: @Gilles Someone below posted something that works right now, and I think most of the other modes I was using normally actually turn tabbing off themselves. There wasn't anything in my `.emacs` file to stop the default tabbing/indentation from happening.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, if you want indentation to use spaces only, I would recommend customizing:

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
```

This forces indentation to use spaces and no tabs. I'm not sure if `web-mode` uses the regular methods for indentation though, so it may not respect this.

Can you give an example file to demonstrate?

Comment: Have added an example to the question. Adding `(setq indent-tabs-mode nil)` doesn't seem to change anything in both `web-mode` and `javascript-mode`.

Comment: I think you should use `setq-default` because `indent-tabs-mode` is buffer-local.

Comment: @progo Okay, that worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: Is it possible to indent with tabs only ? I'm tried different settings, but it indents only with mixed tabs/spaces.

Comment: @Dfr You should add ```(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)``` in your ```.emacs```

Answer (score 5):

Please try this code in your emacs config file to force web-mode indent. I [referred it](http://web-mode.org/) from the web-mode home-page.

```
(require 'web-mode)
(defun my-web-mode-hook ()
  "Hooks for Web mode."
  (setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 2)
)
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook  'my-web-mode-hook)
```

Comment: Would this also work? `(add-hook 'web-mode-hook (lambda () (setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 2)))`