# Use spaces instead of tabs with use-package

Tags: customize, tabs

This is more or less a question of putting the answer from [Make web-mode always indent with spaces](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2355/make-web-mode-always-indent-with-spaces) into the `use-package` declaration.

I want to set tab indent to 2 spaces, and use the spaces throughout the lines, even when reaching 8 spaces etc.

This is my effort so far, I've tried both `setq` and `setq-default`, and I've tried to put the init code in either `:config` or `:init`, but it's not working. When I "describe variable", tab-width is always 8 in the `.go` file that I'm opening.

```el
(use-package go-mode
  :mode "\\.go\\'"
  :config
  (progn
    (setq-default tab-width 2)
    (setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
    ;; tab-width & indent-tabs-mode are both buffer-local so need setq-default
    )

  :init
  (progn
    (setq-default tab-width 2)
    (setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
    )

  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most go specific way to do it is using a go-mode-hook.

In your :config add something like `(add-hook 'go-mode-hook (lambda () (setq tab-width 2)))` That way you set it for every go buffer you open.

Comment: Why would you recommend changing this var at all? `tab-width` never affects the width of indentation inside Emacs.

Comment: Because it does exactly what the xpt is asking for.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be what they need, though.